# How to find out if a word is inside of a line?

Tags: c, search, substring, c-strings, function-definition

I am tring to make a function from exercise in book "Programming in C". The correct function should indicate if a line contain some word, if yes - return its first charcter position(of the word) in the line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int substring (char a[], char b[]);

int main ()
{
    char line1[15], line2[15];
    printf("Print first one\n");
    
    int i = 0;
    char character;
    do 
    {
        character = getchar ();
        line1[i] = character;
        i++;
    }
    while (character != '\n');
    line1[i-1] = '\0';

    printf ("Print the second one\n");
    scanf("%s", line2);

    printf("%s,  %s\n", line1, line2); \\ for checking lines

    int index;

    index = substring (line1, line2);
    printf("The result is: %i\n", index);

}

int substring (char a[], char b[])\*function to determine if a line contains a word, if yes then return its polition, else return -3*\
{
    int len1 = strlen(a), len2 = strlen(b);

    int current1 = 0, current2 = 0;
    bool found = false;
    int result;
    while( current1 < len1 )
    {
        if (a[current1] == b[current2])
        {
            if(!found)
            {
                result = current1+1;
            }
            else 
                found = true;
                    
            while ((a[current1] == b[current2]) && (a[current1] != '\0') && (b[current2] != '\0'))
            {
                
                current1++;
                    
                if(current2+1 == len2)
                    return result;
                    
                current2++;
            }
            current1 = result;
            }
        else
        {
            current2 = 0;
            found = false;
            current1++;
        }
    }
    return -3;
}
```

The problem is somehow in the second function(substring), cause when i try to search for "word" in line "Here is your word", fucntion works properly, but when i try to search "word" in a line "Here is your wwwwword", function returns -3 (which is indication if something went wrong).

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  You need to check if it returns EOF, so you cannot use the smaller integer type.

Comment: Sounds like you have a bug.  Without looking too closely at your code, I would guess that you match the `w` and then then mismatch the `w` with the `o` and then you think you are looking for a `w` again but in fact you should be looking for the `o`.  That is, you aren't resetting your search correctly. IOW, instead of `current2 = 0`, you may need to check if in fact you want `current2 = 1` in some situations.

Comment: Note that this gets more complicated if you are looking for a string like `abcabcd` and you have input `abcabcabcd`, in which case you need to reset that pointer to 4 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is the standard C string function `strstr` that allows to determine whether one string is contained in other string.

If you need to write such a function yourself then your function implementation looks too complicated.

For example the if-else statement

```
    if (a[current1] == b[current2])
    {
        if(!found)
        {
            result = current1+1;
        }
        else 
            found = true;
        // ...
```

does not make a great sense at least by two reasons. The first one is the variable `result` that can be returned from the function in the while loop does not contain the exact index of the found word. And the second one is that `found` never can be equal to true within the function. So the condition in the if statement

```
if( !found )
```

always evaluates to true.

Also you forgot to reset the variable `current2` in the compound statement of the if statement after the while loop.

Apart from this the function parameters should have the qualifier `const` because passed strings are not being changed in the function. And the function return type shall be `size_t`.

The function can look for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t substring( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( s1 );
    size_t n2 = strlen( s2 );

    size_t i = 0;
    bool found = false;

    if (!( n1 < n2 ))
    {
        for ( size_t n = n1 - n2; !found && i <= n; i += !found )
        {
            size_t j = 0;
            while (s2[j] != '\0' && s2[j] == s1[i + j]) ++j;

            found = s2[j] == '\0';
        }
    }

    return found ? i : -1;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *word = "word";
    const char *s1 = "Here is your word";
    const char *s2 = "Here is your wwwwword";

    printf( "%zu\n", substring( s1, word ) );
    printf( "%zu\n", substring( s2, word ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
13
17
```

If a word is not found in the source string then the function returns a value of the type `size_t` that is equal to `-1`.

Pay attention to that the variable character should be declared having the type `int` instead of `char`. Otherwise in general the comparison with `EOF` can produce unexpected result if the type `char` behaves as the type `unsigned char`.